# Take results out of R

Tags: r, dataframe, export, igraph

I run the following code:

```
filenames <- list.files(path=getwd(),pattern="fullmat+.*dta")
list(filenames)

names <-substr(filenames,1,12)
specific <-substr(filenames,8,12)

for(i in names) 
{
  filepath <- file.path("D:/Educacion/PeerEffects/matriz de contactos/Intentos",paste(i,".dta",sep=""))
  assign(i, read.dta13(filepath))
}

for (i in specific){
  assign(paste0("A", i), unname(as.matrix(get(paste0("fullmat", i)))))
  assign(paste0("B", i), graph.adjacency(get(paste0("A", i)), mode = "directed", weighted = NULL, diag = FALSE))
}
```

Now I run the following calculations:

```
##Calculate descriptive statistics from the igraphs (part 1)
for (i in specific)  {
  m <- get(paste0('B', i)) 
  assign(paste0("diameter", i), diameter(m))
  assign(paste0("APL", i), average.path.length(m))
  assign(paste0("transitivity", i), transitivity(m))
  }

##Calculate descriptive statistics from the igraphs (part 2)
for (i in specific)  {
  m <- get(paste0('B', i)) 
  assign(paste0("degree", i), degree(m))
  assign(paste0("close", i), closeness(m))
  assign(paste0("betw", i), betweenness(m))
  assign(paste0("edbetw", i), edge.betweenness(m))
}
```

And what I need is to put all the calculations together and take them to stata. Note that in part 2, the values are at node level and all the igraph objets do not have the same number of nodes.

Comment: Check the R export-import guide: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html and also the packages related to stata: http://www.r-pkg.org/search.html?q=stata

Comment: Thanks but I first need to put the data together within R. I guess it should be a data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve the first part of my question.

```
graphdata = data.frame()
for (i in specific)  {
graphdata[i, 1] = data.frame(get(paste0('diameter', i)))
graphdata[i, 2] = data.frame(get(paste0('APL', i)))
graphdata[i, 3] = data.frame(get(paste0('transitivity', i)))
}
```